# How to tell the difference between selecting and editing/deleting etc. a Kendo Grid row

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a grid with a "change" function which gets fired every time a row is selected or when I click edit/delete/update/cancel button.

What I want is to have an ability to tell the difference, because I only what to execute certain code when a row is selected, and not execute it when I am doing cruds or a row.

```
change: function(e) {

    // Body of the function...
    IF ROW IS SELECTED
        EXECUTE CODE
    ELSE IF ROW IS DELETED, EDITED, ETC.
        DO NOTHING
    END IF

}
```

Is there a way to tell the difference inside the "change" function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "action" property from the event data:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if(e.action == "itemchange") { 
    //update
  } else if (e.action == "add") { 
    //add
  } else { 
    //delete
  }
}
```